# Is anyone else seeing multiple two contributions and two activities for a single online transaction?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, activities

We are in the process of upgrading CiviCRM from v4.4 to v4.7. (Yes, I know it is long overdue.)

We have a Drupal 7 site and use eWAY as our payment processor. Everything works as expected for a front-facing online membership payment on 4.4. However on the  upgraded 4.7.17 staging site, although the contribution and membership functionality is correct (ie, only one payment taken and recorded and membership end date consistent with that), the activities are being double recorded (sort of).

If I signup as a new member then 5 activities are created within 8 seconds. They are (in order):

- two identical contribution activities (same source record id)
- one membership sign up activity
- one change membership status activity from pending to new
- one membership renewal activity

If I renew an existing membership I get at least 4 activities (more if the membership type is changed).  They are:

- two identical contribution activities (same source record id)
- two identical membership renewal activities.

For both new signups and renewals only one membership receipt is sent as expected.

If I make a donation on line I get just one contribution activity as expected.

This double recording of activities happens whether I use a pre-configured membership price set or just choose one of the offered membership types when I set up the contribution page.

Has anyone else seen anything like this or have any insight to offer?

Comment: There's an outstanding PR - might be helpful to you - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9468

Comment: I don't think that is relevant, as our payments are not pending.  Anyway we have too many activities, not too few.

Comment: There was an issue reported along the lines of being described - it's been recorded as fixed in version 4.7.19 https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19243

Comment: Yes it is indeed fixed - our developers did that.